# Conflicting definition of the Hessian matrix: does the order of the partials of a Hessian matrix matter?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, definition, hessian-matrix

On Wikipedia, the Hessian matrix is defined as,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {H} ={\begin{bmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}^{2}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\,\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\,\partial x_{n}}}\\[2.2ex]{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\,\partial x_{1}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}^{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\,\partial x_{n}}}\\[2.2ex]\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\[2.2ex]{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}\,\partial x_{1}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}\,\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}^{2}}}\end{bmatrix}}.}$

However, in the textbook "Optimization" by Chong and Zak, it is written,

[image]

This is different! Or is it?

Is there any problem if I exchanged the order of the partial derivative for all the off-diagonal terms?

Which definition is correct?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, no, [it makes no difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Comment: I don't understand. The Hessian matrix does not exist if $f$ is not twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: It can exist, but then we must decide which of the definitions is the right one. However, *in practice*, we always work with $C^2$ functions, and therefore it doesn't matter.

Comment: If $f$ is twice continuously differentiable then the partial derivative with respect to $x_{i}$ and then $x_{j}$ is equal to the partial derivative with respect to $x_{j}$ and then $x_{i}$.  Normally the second derivatives are continuous and thus the Hessian matrix is symmetric.  Some define the Hessian with the requirement that the second derivatives be continuous.

Comment: @Themanofyourdream It can happen that all partial derivatives of $f$ of second order exist, but $f$ is not twice continuously differentiable, that is the map $x \mapsto D^2f(x)$ is not continuous (this is equivalent to the second partial derivatives not being continuous). But in the case of continuous differentiability it is a theorem that the order of the partial derivatives does not matter.

Comment: It should also be sufficient that $f$ is twice (totally!) differentiable, without requiring continuity of the derivative.

Comment: @JannikPitt Ok, I see. So I imagine that you can compute all the individual partials, but the function defined by the matrix is not continuous. Do you have a simple example?

Comment: @Themanofyourdream Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$Then $f'$ exists, but it is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As argued above, it does not matter all that much in practice. However, the definition that I remember, and given in Wikipedia as well, is $\mathbf{H}(f(x)) = \mathbf{J(\nabla} f(x))$. If you use this definition, the Wikipedia ordering is wrong (but it's a moot point).